# spark submit runs only one single worker node

Tags: apache-spark

We have spark cluster -> master and 2 worker nodes. When we perform spark submit - executors runs only on single worker node. Why does map transformations do not run on both worker nodes? Any settings or factors govern this?
Thanks

Comment: What is your spark-submit statement?

Comment: Have you configured your worker nodes in $SPARK_HOME/conf/slaves file on master node ?

Comment: @Priya updated answer, remove setMaster from code

Comment: Thanks. Removing setMaster code has worked. Now can see executors on both worker nodes.

Comment: Thanks Igor. works after removing "SetMaster"

Answer (score 1):

Please check following:

1. lazy worker(aka slave) is really connected to master
2. Number of partitions of your data, if you have 2 partitions and 1 worker has 4 cores - everything will be done in same worker(you can check by repartitioning your data into more partitions)

@Priya  I think your problem is with setting master in code(seMaster(local)). Code has priority over cli settings. If you remove it youll use master with all resources.

Comment: Thanks

Justin - Kindly find below spark-submit command
Parallelizing customer Ids list (100000 customers in 100 partitions)
Number of partitions (100) is greater than total cores (4) - still processing occurs only on single worker node, other worker node remains idle. Kindly help.

    ./bin/spark-submit -v --deploy-mode cluster --master spark://172.25.35.201:7078 --class par.spark.ParallelCustomer
/home/cloudera/lib/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/ParCustRun.jarr